# Is there a way to add a token logo from a metamask and enable it to be searched?

Tags: metamask

Instead of using the Add Custom Token function in Metamask, tokens such as Chainlink, Uniswap, etc., are searched immediately when searching for tokens, and the logo of the token is checked. Does anyone know how to do this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information [here](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360059582151-How-to-add-a-token-logo), the logos are stored off-chain in their centralized database.

However you can add in a token via [wallet_watchAsset](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-747.md).

Sample code:

```
const tokenAddress = '0xd00981105e61274c8a5cd5a88fe7e037d935b513';
const tokenSymbol = 'TUT';
const tokenDecimals = 18;
const tokenImage = 'http://placekitten.com/200/300';

try {
  // wasAdded is a boolean. Like any RPC method, an error may be thrown.
  const wasAdded = await ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_watchAsset',
    params: {
      type: 'ERC20', // Initially only supports ERC20, but eventually more!
      options: {
        address: tokenAddress, // The address that the token is at.
        symbol: tokenSymbol, // A ticker symbol or shorthand, up to 5 chars.
        decimals: tokenDecimals, // The number of decimals in the token
        image: tokenImage, // A string url of the token logo
      },
    },
  });

  if (wasAdded) {
    console.log('Thanks for your interest!');
  } else {
    console.log('Your loss!');
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.